# Is there a function on a compact interval that is differentiable but not Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Consider a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, does there exist a differentiable function that is not Lipschitz continuous?

After discussing this with friends we have come to the conclusion that none exist. However there is every chance we are wrong. If it is true that none exist how could we go about proving that? It is true that [if $f$ is *continuously* differentiable then $f$ is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795950/differentiability-and-lipschitz-continuity?rq=1), but what if we don't assume the derivative is continuous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = x^{3/2} \sin(1/x)$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ (in particular $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)/x = 0$), but it is not Lipschitz (the derivative $f'(x)$ is unbounded).

Comment: You mean $x^{3/2}\,\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: Yes @JuliánAguirre, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Boundedness of the derivative is a sufficient condition for a function being Lipschitzian. I'm not sure it is necessary.

Comment: @egreg It is necessary: if $|f(x) - f(y)| \le K |x-y|$ for all $x$, $y$, then $|f'(x)| = |\lim_{y \to x} (f(y) - f(x))/(x-y)| \le K$. (The converse is proved used the MVT.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm unsure why  you're looking at $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)/x$ and not $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} f^{\prime}(x)$.

Comment: @mark $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} (f(x) - f(0))/(x - 0)$ is the definition of $f'(0)$. The equation $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)$ is only true when $f$ is continuously differentiable ($C^1$) at $x = 0$.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, that was a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

If you require $f'$ to be continious then there can be no $f$ since $f'([0,1])$ is compact and indeed bounded.

Comment: No, Michael Albanese had alrady suggested that, but $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: thanks! I would like to delete it but I can't find a button to do that on my phone app!

Comment: since I can't delete at least I write something uselfull i hope! :)