# Does the Mean Value Theorem imply that the derivative is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show if $f$ defined on a closed interval has a continuous derivative throughout the interval, then it is Lipschitz continuous on the interval.

Using the Mean Value Theorem the proof almost follows trivially since we can say for $\zeta \in [a,b]$ $\implies$ $|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\zeta)| |x - y|$. We are nearly there, however I am unsure if the derivative being bounded follows from the MVT as well? Or is there something left to show.

***Please*** do not supply me with a proof, a simple **hint** will suffice.

Comment: The key is the continuity of the derivative.

Comment: Hint: You need to add in that the image of a compact set is compact and that a compact subset of a Euclidean space is closed and bounded.

Comment: Can you imagine a continuous unbounded function on a compact set?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795950/differentiability-and-lipschitz-continuity?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476072/continuous-differentiability-implies-lipschitz-continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;f'\;$ is continuous in compact interval it is bounded there and you have $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$

Comment: -1: it is not true that every continuous function on an interval is Lipchitz. Try $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Comment: The derivative of f is continuous, not f itself

Comment: Replacing $f$ by $f^\prime$ after "Since" would fix the answer, yet a reference to the [theorem used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) would be nice.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Not all function but the derivative is bounded

Comment: @BenS. What I wrote is not Lipschitz for $\;f\;$ ?

Comment: After the edit, this post indeed answers the question.

Comment: I first typed \prime but it was very big, so I erased but forgot to type $\;f'\;$ again. Sorry.

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras Before the edit, it wasn't an answer. Now it is, so I deleted my comment.